# Limit access to server using MAC address or certificate

Tags: 14.04, networking

My server has a static IP and I've set up a website so that computers on the same network can access the website using the IP address. For example, you can type 192.168.1.1/#!/ in the address bar of a browser and connect to my website.

I'm looking for a way to limit connections to the Ubuntu desktop either with MAC address or certificates that are on computers that I give access to.

Is there a way to limit connections in such a way?

Comment: Which Web server are you using?

Comment: Sorry meant to say that the desktop is itself a server. I'm using the meanstack framework to start up the website.

Comment: Keep in mind that MAC address filtering can be bypassed easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iptables rules to limit access based on MAC address. Here is an example from my own rule set to not allow packets from a specific MAC:

```
# Drop packets from a certain MAC address
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m mac --mac-source 00:14:BF:BC:25:EE -j LOG --log-prefix "BEFSR81:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m mac --mac-source 00:14:BF:BC:25:EE -j DROP
```

where:

```
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
EXTIF="eth1"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"
EXTIP="your static IP address"
```

However, if the desire was to allow based on MAC address, the rules would be something like:

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Allow packets from a certain MAC address and no others
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m mac --mac-source 00:14:BF:BC:25:EE -j LOG --log-prefix "BEFSR81:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m mac --mac-source 00:14:BF:BC:25:EE -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -j DROP
```

Note: for the allow version, some other specific ACCEPTs might be required.
You may or may not want the logging lines. If you keep them, make sure they do not flood your log files.

Comment: Is this rule to allow specific MAC address or block specific MAC address? I would like to only allow a few MAC addresses.

Comment: @jimbob Replace `DROP` with `ACCEPT` and set a rule up after this that simply drops all other traffic.  Note that doing that, you can totally nuke your system.  Also note that MAC only works on the local network, it won't work from Internet in.

Comment: It will be on the same network.

Comment: @ThomasW. I was editing my answer and didn't see your comment until afterwards. I think my edit covers your comment. Note that my example is for the internet side of things, but in my case it is from another IP address on the same subnet (i.e. my other public static IP address) and so the MAC address stuff works. However, in general the end user would only get the MAC address of their ISP's router.

Comment: Is there a way to block access using certificates? I feel as if blocking all other MAC addresses might be a drastic step.

Comment: Also how would I go about undoing the MAC address filtering

Comment: If you want to flush the rule set on the fly then `sudo /sbin/iptables -F INPUT`. Certificates, I don't know, but I also don't understand the difference in the two methods.

Comment: @DougSmythies I've been sniffing WAN traffic recently, and MAC addresses aren't really that usable from Internet-sourced packets, if the system you're trying to reach is behind a firewall or such.  Because at that point, it loses the Internet-sourced MAC address.  You may wish to assume a "local network" stance, not a "from the 'net" stance.

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes, of course. In my case my Ubuntu server is my internet facing router / firewall.

Comment: @jimbob: You might still be able to use the MAC based iptables rules by restricting them a little, say to only protocol tcp and only port 80.

Comment: Use reject with iptables. To be honest I do not think mac is any more secure then ip. I suggest you use https:// + password Auth or ssh as those protocols encrypt traffic. Http is not encrypted and one can read the content from the packets

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I assumed the OP's LAN is DHCP and that the computers desired to be allowed might not always have the same IP address. Yes, on a LAN where one wants to be polite REJECT might be better.

Comment: Reject is better outside a Lan too